# Google spreadsheet text length validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am working on Google spreadsheet. I am trying to make a validation rule on the text length.
For example the text length must be equal to 12 characters which includes number, on dash and one capital character.
Example:
123-56C89112

I tried to search in google groups but no result! can you help in this please

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data > Validation > Custom Formula is

```
=REGEXMATCH(B3, "^(?=.{12}$)(?=(^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*$))(?=(^[^-]*[-]{1}[^-]*$)).*")
```

I'm not an expert on Regex so this may be a bit over the top, but it appears to work:

```
^(?=.{12}$)(?=(^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*$))(?=(^[^-]*[-]{1}[^-]*$)).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kLpK0xv_04O_v7zC)

This allows any string with exactly 12 characters, 1 upper case letter and 1 dash.

**EDIT**: The (Lookahead) Regex doesn't seem to work in Spreadsheets (see comment)

**EDIT2**: Using a custom function like the following seems to work, but only if you use warnings (instead of rejections) for some reason (bug?)

```
function test(myString) { 
return myString.match("^(?=.{12}$)(?=(^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*$))(?=(^[^-]*[-]{1}[^-]*$)).*")!=null;
 }
```

Comment: That would require the first three values to be numbers - as far as I understand this is not a given

Comment: Apparently Spreadsheets doesn't allow for lookahead regex'. I'll try it with a custom function on AppScript, but I don't see how you can solve this with common functions